# 1997 Honda Odyssey - How do I know if the valves are still good after both the timing belts broke?

Tags: engine, honda, odyssey, valve-timing

I hired a mechanic to replace my crankshaft pulley sensor. He ended up doing something wrong. We tried to crank it and it sounded like a dead battery and the sensor broke and hit the oil pump. Put a hole in it and both the timing belts broke.

How do I know if the valves are still good? Please help, I need to know what do. i have the parts to fix it but how do i know if the valves are still good?

Comment: You mention that you have two timing belts. Is this a V6?

Comment: @Zaid that generation had the F22B (same as the accord). Next generation is when the V6 was put in (J35)

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you have a 4 cylinder.

You need to remove the valve cover. If the valves are adjustable then unadjust them until all the valves are free. Remove the spark plugs. Use a leakdown tester to induce compressed air into the cylinders. The tester will shows the amount of leak down and where it is coming from. If it's coming out of the tail pipe then bent exhaust valve. If it's coming out of the intake manifold then its a bent intake valve.

20 to 30 percent leakage is tolerable. Anything beyond that probably means bent valves.

Comment: 4 cylinder is the only engine available in this model.  That test will work but since it is apart I would pop on a new timing belt and check the valve adjustment. There is a good chance on this engine that the valves are OK.

Comment: as a side note the 2nd "timing" belt is the balancer. You can leave it off long enough to test if you have bent valves by cranking it up, but the leak down test sounds like a much safer option